# $\zeta(2)$ Euler's proof (Basel problem)

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

At one point Euler assumes that 
$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{n\pi} \right)\left(1-\frac{-x}{n\pi} \right)$$
Why does he assume that? If we factor random functions according to their roots, we can conclude
$$e^x \frac{\sin x}{x}= \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{n\pi} \right)\left(1-\frac{-x}{n\pi} \right)=\frac{\sin x}x$$

Comment: look into his book introductio in analysin infinitorum (english translation exists); he explains very well why this second formula fails (the terms don't diminish fast enough - he used rather an "infinite number" that he denoted $i$, but his argument can be translated to a convergence argument)

Comment: There's more to it than just the zeros. I don't know how Euler did it, but one can look at the logarithmic derivatives, and the value at certain points, to determine the non-vanishing factor in a product representation.